# Keep track of animation in scenekit (swift)

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am trying to rotate a geometry on the right as long as I am touching the right side of the screen and left when touching the left side. When not touching the screen, the animation should stop.
For this I came up with the following code which works until I press again the screen and the geometry goes back to its original state instead of starting the rotatation from the previous position.
I also need to keep track of the angle for future development and node.rotation.w always returns 0.

```
func respondToLPGesture(gestureRecognize: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{
    let scnView = self.view as SCNView
    let spin = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "rotation")
    spin.duration = 2
    spin.repeatCount = .infinity

    let p = gestureRecognize.locationInView(scnView)
    switch gestureRecognize.state
        {
    case .Began:
        //Determine rotation direction
        if p.x < scnView.frame.width / 2 {
            //spin.fromValue = NSValue(SCNVector4: SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, w: angle))
            //spin.toValue = NSValue(SCNVector4: SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, w: angle + 2*Float(M_PI)))
            spin.byValue = NSValue(SCNVector4: SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, w: 2*Float(M_PI)))
            scnView.scene.rootNode.childNodes[1].addAnimation(spin, forKey: "spin around")
        }
        else {
            spin.byValue = NSValue(SCNVector4: SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, w: 2*Float(-M_PI)))
            scnView.scene.rootNode.childNodes[1].addAnimation(spin, forKey: "spin around")
        }
    case .Ended:
        println(scnView.scene.rootNode.childNodes[1].rotation.w) // Always returns 0.
        scnView.scene.rootNode.childNodes[1].pauseAnimationForKey("spin around")

    default:
        println("Inside default")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watching WWDC 2014 "What's New in SceneKit" helped me to find the answer.
To track a node position/rotation in Scenekit use "presentationNode". 
Example below:

```
let angle = scnView.scene.rootNode.childNodes[1].presentationNode().rotation.w
```

Using the following will return the value of the targeted end of the animation which is always 0 in my code example:

```
let angle = scnView.scene.rootNode.childNodes[1].rotation.w
```